# Cross compiling libSDL

Tags: linux, compiling, configure, cross-compilation

I'm trying to cross-compile libSDL version 1.2 for a custom made, Debian based Linux system. The toolchain I'm using is already configured properly so that I just run `gcc`/`g++` on the desired code and the resulting output is compatible with the target machine.

When I run `./configure --help` in the libSDL source directory, I see that I can basically just set some environment variables to point to my cross-compiler.

However, I also see the following options:

```
System types:
  --build=BUILD     configure for building on BUILD [guessed]
  --host=HOST       cross-compile to build programs to run on HOST [BUILD]
```

I looked into the `configure.in`, `build-scripts/config.sub`, and `build-scripts/config.guess` files but couldn't really figure out how it works.

Are these options required? If not, is it a good idea to use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is 'yes', I should specify both. The `--build` flag will be the architecture of the machine doing the compiling... the scripts can do a good job of guessing what this will be, but it's better to be safe than sorry and actually specify yourself. The `--host` flag is the necessary part in making this cross-compilation actually work. When my `--build` and `--host` flags weren't the same values (for example, i686-generic versus x86_64-linux), the configure scripts would realize that I'm trying to cross compile.

Instead of simply resorting to local compiler (on the host machine, specified somewhere in $PATH), the configure scripts would find a compiler suite (compiler, linker, etc.) either specified as flags or an environment variables (e.g. $CPPFLAGS, $CC, $AR, etc.) and use those.

Answer (score 0):

`--build=BUILD` - is the system where on which the compiled compiler is goint to be ran. This is only for building a cross-compiler on architecture A that will run on architecture B and produce code for architecture C.

`--host=HOST` - is the system where the compilation happens

`--target=TARGET` - is the system the compiled binaries are going to run on

See e.g. this [cross-compilation introduction](http://landley.net/writing/docs/cross-compiling.html).

Comment: This isn't quite the answer since I'm simply building a library, not an entire compiler. The situation you're talking about is the Canadian cross compilation

Comment: You are right it is not answer to the questions: *Are these options required? If not, is it a good idea to use them?* Rather it is an explanation of what the options do (especially since you are compiling a library but mentioning `--build` which is really used only for the toolchain).